# Does Safe{Core} support React Native?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to use the Account Abstraction (AA) SDK, but I haven’t found information anywhere about support or implementation plans for React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Safe{Core} AA SDK is built with TypeScript, meaning that using it inside a React Native app should not be an issue. However, there are some kits in the SDK that integrate third party services (like Web3Auth or Stripe, to name a couple of them) that might have specific requirements and dependencies with packages that don't work with React Native.

The Safe{Core} AA SDK was not tested with React Native and is not in the short-term roadmap. It might or might not work.